# How can I modify Unity 12.04's power cog menu

Tags: unity, menu, menu-bar

"System Settings..." and the randomly chosen among many "Displays..." go to the same program, while I have to remember ccsm, [dg]conf-editor and a few others mentioned in various articles.  Or I must waste scarce launcher space to pin them.

I would love to have them all in one space, and that would ideally be the cog menu.  Editing files (preferably in ~) or starting commands at session start, whatever it takes is fine with me!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL. VTC this unanswered question as `not reproducible`.